what's the difference between "order by created_time desc" and "order by -created_time" in mysql
Normally, I would take them as the same.
why different performance ?
BY using mysql:5.7
For a table holds 10 million rows
-- order by created_time desc



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
points_full_table

range
created_time_index
created_time_index
5

4986750
100.00
Using index condition



-- order by -created_time



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
points_full_table

ALL
created_time_index



9973500
50.00
Using where; Using filesort



-- TAKE 0.018S
select SQL_NO_CACHE * from sample.points_full_table where created_time > '2023-01-01' order by created_time desc limit 1000;

-- TAKE 5.323S
select SQL_NO_CACHE * from sample.points_full_table where created_time > '2023-01-01' order by -created_time limit 1000;



Please publish the table definition as text. Also did you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Is order by -created_time a typo and should be order by created_time ?

The expression -created_time (a column with unary minus) have numeric context. The server needs to convert the datatime value to numeric one, alter the sign then sort by the result - hence, you see slower execution and  filesort in the execution plan.

And I thought that -created_time was a typo and should be created_time. In every tests that I made asc was faster.

The performance difference occurs because ORDER BY created_time DESC can efficiently utilize an index on created_time to scan the data in reverse order without needing a filesort, making it faster.
In contrast, ORDER BY -created_time prevents MySQL from using the index efficiently, forcing it to perform a filesort to reorder the data, which is slower.

sorry for my edit errors, conditions are reversed, ORDER BY created_time DESC  is using Using index condition, much faster than -created_time

Order by created_time desc will return latest inserted data first in descending order where other will work inverse and return records in ascending order

Please share more details. What makes you think that it really returns the latest inserted data first? Nobody hinders you from setting created_time to any arbitrary value during inserting new data
